# Application clone for various domain extensions hurts SEO?

Tags: seo, single-page-application

On the server I have 3 different directories which are named by domains I own in hosting/domains provider.

- `example.com`
- `example.co.uk`
- `example.de`

In every of this directory there is clone of exact same single page application (SPA).

There isn't any changes in code of this app clones. The only change is default language of page content but application itself determine the language basing on extension or browser language (when .com).

Because the hosting provider automatically created directories basing on domains I bought it seemed to be the easiest way to just put clone in each folder.

It worked and I have my SPA working correctly at .com, .co.uk, and .de extensions but now I wonder if such architecture is good for SEO. Shouldn't I have one SPA in some separate directory and just do some redirections in .htaccess for various domain extensions?

Comment: I'm not sure how SEO plays a part here. How do the search engines know whether you have one instance of your app (shared between three sites) or three separate instances? This affects development, not SEO. Or have I missed something?

Comment: How about content?   You can duplicate code as much as you want, but it is content that matters to Google.  Is the content the same between the instances, or would they all look identical to Googlebot?   Presumably, the language would mean unique content on .de at least.

Comment: The text content of app is pre-rendered with server-side-rendering so to the browser goes text which is already translated to extension language. So when I hit .de then on server text is translated from default locale (english) to german and then goes to the browser. But HTML markup is same for every clone. So short answer is - only text language is different in this 3 applications in google eyes.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller But although content language change I still want to know if maybe it's better approach for SEO to have 1 app on the server and just do redirections?

Comment: There is no way anybody can know whether you host it in one place and rewrite different sites to it or whether you copy the app unless they have access to your sever.  There is no way that Google could know that.